# Change to method declaration

Tags: c#

I was doing an assessment and this is one of the questions I got:

Which of the following changes cannot be made to the declaration of the C# method call(`document.SaveAs(...)`) below to streamline the code:

```
object fileName = "Test.docx";
object missing = Missing.Value;

document.SaveAs(ref fileName,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing,
                ref missing);
```

- Replace `object missing = Missing.Value;` with `object Missing`
- Remove `object fileName = "Test.docx";` statement
- Remove all occurences of `ref`
- Replace `ref fileName` with `FileName: "Test.docx"`
- Replace `ref fileName` with `FileName: ref fileName`.

I already did the assessment, I'm just curious because I actually did not get the question.

Thanks.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've receive the results and "unfortunately" got just 89% which according to the recruiter, is not enough... anyway, like I said before I choose options D and E, and got the question partially right, and given that I can only select 3 options at the most, options A, B, C and D can't be all correct.

Comment: `ref`... `ref` everywhere... What is this I don't even...

Comment: this is among the worst code I've ever seen...the assessment should be assessed.

Comment: I did read the question, but I did not understand it, that´s why I'm asking, I've got not clue about what they are asking.

Comment: Don't worry I'm just as lost as you.

Comment: @Timmerz - To be fair, it does provide some good testing of `ref` knowledge (even if the example is contrived). For example, the first bullet point can't be done because you can't pass an uninitalized variable to a ref parameter. I think this assignment could be done pretty quickly if OP creates a console app and tries each bullet point out and see what the output is.

Comment: @keyboardP but it says to the declaration, not to the use. I was thinking about the same, but the declaration word, changed my mind.

Comment: @Marco - Not sure I follow. If you replaced `object missing = Missing.Value;` with `object missing;` your program wouldn't compile so that bullet point can't be done. I assume that's what the teacher is looking for.

Comment: @keyboardP It was an online IKM assessment.

Comment: folks there is no reason to downvote him, the question is ok, Marco could try these options in the compiler yes, but the question is still a question and if you don't like it don't answer or comment but no need to downvote.

Comment: @DavidePiras - Just for the record, I didn't downvote :)

Comment: @keyboardP I thought they were referring to the actual method declaration: document.SaveAs(...), which they did not even provide. I think you're right.

Comment: @DavidePiras I would David, but the problem is that I don't really understand what the question is asking, so I don't really know what to test... changing the unknown method signature, changing the code prior to the call... but like I said, I think keyboardP is right.

Comment: @Marco - I can understand your confusion as they mentioned changing the method declaration.

Comment: @Marco From the context it looks like a Word interop method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.saveas.aspx The Office interop all looks like that.

Comment: @keyboardP I hate this kind of tests, which are not straight to the point, unfortunately more and more companies seems to use this companies to test candidates.

Comment: @Timmerz It looks like that method is part of the Word Interop.

Comment: Were they expecting me to know the method signature in case it was one of those com calls? o_O

Comment: I hate assessment tests...its like half of the stuff I have never used in my career and seems worded by a non programmer.

Comment: @Marco - OT but I wish you luck with the assessment(s) results :) I know what you mean with some of the questions I've seen in exams and such!

Comment: @that's exactly how I feel. I rather have them ask me to do some algorithm. The problem is that most of these recruiters don't seem to understand that, it is more important that you know how to think, and only then if you know all the corners of the tool.

Comment: @keyboardP Lets see how it goes.

Comment: @keyboardP no they did not have the object in the parameters.

Comment: @keyboardP but knowing the signature would it make any difference to the understanding that you have for the question?

Comment: @Marco No not really, it was a minor thing.

Comment: gonna sleep thinking about this, feck. I've got a few more questions I did not really understood, I shall post them tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

As the last one is causing confusion, this might help.

```
public class Document
{
    public void SaveAs(ref string DocName)
    {

    }
}
```

Notice the parameter name is `DocName`. Usually this parameter name is thought of as something only used by the method and unimportant outside the method, but since .NET 4 (I think?), C# can used named parameters in this format. If you're familiar with Objective-C then you'll see these often. With named parameters, `DocName` is important.

We can now call this method like this

```
string fName = "Test.docx";
Document d = new Document();
d.SaveAs(DocName: ref fName);
```

Note that `DocName` has to be used, otherwise the compiler will thrown an error (so you couldn't do `d.SaveAs(RandomName: ref fName);`). Also note that a string variable is passed and not instantiated within the method declaration (`d.SaveAs(DocName: "Test.docx");`).

Comment: Not sure if I am getting you, but one thing is for sure, if you change the method declaration to something like this: `SaveAs(string fileName = "Test.docx")` you could remove the first line of code: `object fileName = "Test.docx";`. In this case I would select only option D, because that is a method declaration change, I would say B as well, but that is a code change.

Comment: Still optional parameters would require you to change the order of the parameters, so I'm not even sure about D, because you would have to change the method call as well O_o

Comment: You would be right about B being able to be changed but only if the optional parameter was the only parameter or it was at the end. So even if that change was made, because the parameter is at the beginning, that would not be allowed.

Comment: "so I'm not even sure about D", I actually wanted to B. Anyway, a question which has multiple interpretation is just wrong, I just wonder how many good programmers are actually "rejected" because they miss these "tests". Thanks a lot for your comments @keyboard

Comment: I think mentioning the `method declaration call` only but having options to change the other parts can be confusing. You're welcome, hope the rest of the questions went well.

Answer (score 0):

- Replace object missing = Missing.Value; with object Missing Remove : will give an error, use of unassigned local variable
- object fileName = "Test.docx" :  : will give an error, use of unassigned local variable
- statement Remove all occurences of ref : this is fine, will turn the referenced variables into local ones

The last two i have no idea about, horribly worded.

Comment: I think the last two are about `Named Parameters`.

Comment: Last two bullets: `Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified`

Comment: @Romoku I actually choose the last two bullets. I had no idea, but those seemed to be the only ones related to the method declaration.

Comment: Yes iambeanie, that was the problem, horrible worded.