# Get enum value from string

Tags: c#

I did an online assessment and I'm trying to understand the results, and here one of the questions I did already:

[Change to method declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180480/change-to-method-declaration)

So the question is this:

[image]

[image]

and the report says:

[image]

I can't see why my answer is marked as partially right, am I missing something? Also the question says this is a string manipulation question, although to me it has nothing to do with that subject.

Marco

**UPDATE**

Answer C is not right, I was mistaken by the fact that I used the var keyword and not the actual enum.

Comment: Yes, you have the correct answer. Full credit should be given for correct answers. This is quite stupid in my opinion.

Comment: @rmayer06 That´s what I though, because I could not see any mistake there. I could leave like this, and not worry about the results, but I wonder how many good developers lose good opportunities because of these mistakes.

Comment: Please mind that all are var.

Comment: Yes, answer C is not correct. Enum.Parse returns an object. This is no problem when using vars but not when you use a strongly typed enum like ConnectionState.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Oh I see, my mistake then, the 3rd option returns an object.

Comment: @Dirk, yes you guys are right, I missed that, I really thought it would return the enum value itself., my bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: I didn't see that you had option C checked before... haha. Sorry. Chalk it up to cognitive bias - I automatically disregarded incorrect answers :)

Comment: @Marco: BTW where did you do your assesment. Can you provide the link.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal it was a IKM assessment, given to my by a recruiter, it is not an open assessment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've ticked *two* options. The one you've shown the mouse pointer at is fine, but the other one isn't.

Try it so you can see why. Note that as of .NET 4, there's [`Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) which is generic, and thus less annoying in a few ways. Unfortunately, `TryParse` isn't constrained to force `TEnum` to be an enum type...  which it couldn't be if it were declared in C#, but could be in IL. See my [Unconstrained Melody project](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) for an alternative approach here, if you're interested. (If you just want to know why you only got partial credit, I completely understand...)

(And I agree it's not really "string manipulation" as such.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon, I really though the parse would return the enum value, not an object. It would be an easy one to spot if you were using the IDE, and I'm sure I've came across this issue before, anyway it is good to know :)

Comment: @Marco: Well at execution time it *will* return the enum value. But consider what the declaration of `Parse` *has* to look like, given that it's a non-generic method.

Comment: Yes, I missed that, too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Question asks which one will return an enum. In that case fourth option is right. Third option will return an object(albeit your enum will be encapsulated in an object).

The trick here is `var`. All are assigned to `var`. So even if it returns an object or an enum all are accepted in `var`.

Here is proof.

[image]

Comment: Look at the Q in the quiz. It is asking which one returns an `enum`, it doesn't say which one compiles.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad, Nikhil is right, if I use the actual enum rather that then a variant it won´t compile.

Comment: @Marco yes that's right, but before editing he said both options are correct.