# Implicit Vs explicit convers

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I did an online assessment and I'm trying to understand the results, and here are a few of the questions I did already:

[Get enum value from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253719/get-enum-value-from-string)

[Change to method declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180480/change-to-method-declaration)

[image]

So the question is this:

I got this one partially right as well, after reading about the subject I would choose just option A and D, can you guys confirm?

Thanks a lot.

Marco

Comment: Certainly not B, C, or E. I don't like the wording of D. I don't know what they mean by "done." You can *define* an implicit conversion using the implicit keyword, but you would not *consume and perform* such a conversion using that keyword. So what do they mean by "done?" I would simply just choose A.

Comment: Only one I'd check is A, but even that is dubious thanks to the implicit cast to `X` that `foreach(X x in...)` does even if there is only an explicit conversion to `X`.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, yes the wording does not help.

Comment: @CodesInChaos we have the implict operator, that´s why I was wondering about D as well.

Comment: @Marco The keyword `implicit` is used to declare the operator, but not to do the conversion.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I guess you're talking about D, but it is not explicit if they are referring to the usage or to the declaration of an implicit conversion, that's why I choose it, at least it is not explicit to me, what they are really asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implicit conversion does not need a cast:

```
int a = 10;
long b = a;
```

An explicit conversion *does* need a cast:

```
long a = 10;
int b = (int)a;
```

To *define* (not invoke) an implicit conversion, the `implicit` keyword is used:

```
public static implicit operator MyOther(MyThis obj);
```

To *define* an explicit conversion, the `explicit` keyword is used:

```
public static explicit operator MyOther(MyThis obj);
```

Usually, explicit conversions are used when information might be lost through the conversion, or an exception may occur. For example, converting a 64-bit `long` integer to a 32-bit `int` integer might lose the 32 most-significant bits of information.

So, I am sure A is true, B, C and E are false. I don't understand the question for D. If they mean *invoking* the implicit conversion, then it is false. If they mean *defining* the implicit conversion, then it is true.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I do know the difference between both, at least some of the diferences, I rather have a problem understanding the wording of the questions

Comment: About the answer D, I am not sure either, because it is just like you said, you use the implicit keyword when defining and implicit conversion.